# HTML how do I position two images one above the other?

Tags: html, css

As the title says, I have two "social icons" classified as  inside of one div id as "socialicons", I was wondering how - in CSS - I can instead of having the img's horizontal to eachother, vertical(one above the other). Remember these are inside the same div and I am calling them in CSS via the div id.

Answer (score 0):

In your image's css, use `display:block;`  Images are `display:inline-block;` by default

Comment: when I do that the two images separate, with one being positioned on the far left and the other on the far right, although one is higher than the other

Comment: does your div have a set height?  it might just be that it can't fit under the other image.

Comment: Indeed it does, I'll try remove that now

Comment: I am afraid not, nvm I shall just change my design. Thanks for the help bud